# How to change Firebase Cloud Functions URI Scheme

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, uri, icalendar

I'm creating a Firebase Cloud Functions to return an iCal calendar to subscribe to. I can get the `http(s)://` version working for subscribing.

However, I've no idea how to change the URI scheme. I want it to accept `webcal://` as well to support native subscription when clicking on the link. How can I do that?